# Snapping with custom translate modal

Tags: snapping

does anyone know if it is possible to have a custom modal translate (such as the code below) but also have it respect blenders snapping?

```
if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
    x, y = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    self.mouse_path.append((x, y))
    obj = context.object
    if obj:
        loc = region_2d_to_location_3d(context.region, context.space_data.region_3d, (x, y), (0, 0, 0))
        obj.location = loc
```